# Cannot connect Spring Boot -Google App Engine with Postgresql - Cloud Sql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

So I have been trying to connect my Spring Boot Application (in Google App Engine) with a cloud SQL (Postgresql) and have been receiving the following errors:

```
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800182Z org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed. 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800183Z    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:272) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800184Z    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800185Z    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800186Z    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800187Z    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800188Z    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar!/:na] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800189Z    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar!/:na] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800190Z    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar!/:na] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800191Z    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar!/:na] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800192Z    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar!/:na] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800193Z    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar!/:na] 
...
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800269Z Caused by: java.net.SocketException: already connected 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800270Z    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:569) ~[na:1.8.0_222] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800271Z    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666) ~[na:1.8.0_222] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800272Z    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800273Z    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7] 
A 2020-03-15T04:58:41.951800274Z    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

I couldn't understand what it means by "java.net.SocketException: already connected"

Here is my configuration file in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=${URL}
spring.datasource.username=${USER}
spring.datasource.password=${PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.enabled=true


spring.cloud.gcp.projectId={projectId}
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instanceName={projectId}:{region}:{instanceName}
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://google/{dbname}?cloudSqlInstance={projectId}:{region}:{dbname}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user={user}&password={password}
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.databaseName={DBname}
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.userName={user}
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.password={password}

spring.cloud.gcp.sql.jdbcDriver=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name={projectId}:{region}:{instanceName}
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name={DBname}


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

And here is my app.yaml configuration file:

```
runtime: java
env: flex
runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8
env_variables:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "gcp,postgresql"
  URL: "jdbc:postgresql://google/{dbName}?cloudSqlInstance={projectId}:{region}:{instanceName}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user={user}&password={password}"
  USER: "{user}"
  PASSWORD: "{password}"

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "{projectId}:{region}:{instanceName}"

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 10
  volumes:
    - name: ramdisk1
      volume_type: tmpfs
      size_gb: 0.5
```

The cloud SQL configuration is public IP.
I would appreciate any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your url:

```
URL:"jdbc:postgresql://google/{dbName}?cloudSqlInstance={projectId}:{region}:{instanceName}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user={user}&password={password}"
```

Should be:

```
URL:"jdbc:postgresql:///<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=<MYSQL_USER_NAME>&password=<MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD>"
```

> [Note:](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory) The **host** portion of the JDBC URL is currently unused, and has no
>   effect on the connection process. The SocketFactory will get your
>   instances IP address base on the provided cloudSqlInstance arg.